# IntelliJ IDEA Aspectj (Ajc compiler) takes too much time to load classes after every Make

Tags: java, performance, compiler-construction, intellij-idea, aspectj

I wonder if there is a way to reduce compilation time when using Ajc compiler with IntelliJ. I have rather big project, i would like to use AspectJ with, but unfortunatly when I've tried to work with it i found out that it takes too much time for Ajc to load all classes and it is doing it every time i hit Make(save .java file with Eclipse Mode plugin). So every tiny change causes 3 second of class loading...
Is there a way to shorten this time? Preferably get rid of class loading at all. It is extremly time consuming as it is now and I had to stop using Ajc and switch back to Javac which is nearly instant compared to Ajc.
I am using IntelliJ IDEA 10, AspectJ 1.6.11. Not sure if more info is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment IDEA uses a classpath as an aspectpath - this allows to avoid UI configuration, but causes long compilation time and increased memory consumption. This is especially notable on a big projects.

In IDEA 11 (starting from a next EAP) aspectpath will be configurable.

Comment: [EAP build 110.137](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+11+EAP) just released. If your project is Maven-based then aspect path should be configured automatically on re-import.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, IntelliJ v11 was supposed to have this fix for AJC in it, but they discovered a bug with incremental compilation for AJC so they've switched off incremental compilation AJC altogether in v11, which obviously makes compile time even worse. See http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-76479